# Replace only text within multiple divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

I can't replace text inside Div or Containers. I just want to replace the text but it doesn't work for me. I've tried several ways but it still doesn't work.

I just want to replace the "-" with empty "". But it should just be the text without overriding the tag classes.

```
<div class="reemplazo-guion">
  <div class="kt-btn-wrap kt-btn-wrap-0">
   <a class="kt-button" href="#" style="border-radius:10px;border-width:1px" >
     <span class="kt-btn-inner-text">Accede Ahora al Método <strong><em>G-e-n-g-h-i-s K-h-a-n</em></strong></span>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.reemplazo-guion').contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).each(function(){
      this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('-','');
    });
});
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/xpcf49mh

Comment: Assuming the hyphens are always only ever contained in the `em` element then you can just use `$('.reemplazo-guion em').text((i, t) => t.replace(/-/g, ''));` - https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/p62ahL1x/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's the detail, i can't assume that, you have to replace all the text from a parent class.

Comment: Instead of `this.textContent.replace('-','')` you should use `this.textContent.replaceAll('-','')`. Otherwise only the first instance in each text node will be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in order to get all the text nodes within `.reemplazo-guion` you will need to add  a `*` to the selector (resulting in  `".reemplazo-guion *"`) as `.contents()` will only pick up the *direct children* of the jQuery-selected element(s). With the `*` wildcard *all* "-"s can now be found and replaced by blanks:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.reemplazo-guion *').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(){
  this.textContent = this.textContent.replaceAll('-','');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="reemplazo-guion">
  <div class="kt-btn-wrap kt-btn-wrap-0">
   <a class="kt-button" href="#" style="border-radius:10px;border-width:1px" >
 <span class="kt-btn-inner-text">Accede A-ho-ra al Método <strong><em>G-e-n-g-h-i-s K-h-a-n</em></strong></span>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try below code, it is working for the provided HTML content.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var HTMLContent = $('.reemplazo-guion').html().replace(/-/g, '');
  $('.reemplazo-guion').html(HTMLContent)
});
```

Comment: This will remove all hyphens anywhere in the HTML, so it will affect the classnames too, for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats why we use jQuery to strict the target DOM, you can set whatever place you want.